# How to create a link between two models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

There are 2 models

1. School
2. Director

It is necessary to make sure that in the school model there is a director (full name), and in the Director model there is the name of the school

```
from django.db import models


class Director(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Surname')
    school = models.CharField() #<----????
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/img/", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=10000, verbose_name='photo')
    birthday = models.DateField( verbose_name='birthday')


class school(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='name')
    capacity = models.IntegerField(max_length=20,verbose_name='capacity')
    registration_is = models.BooleanField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Registration')
    director_name = models.ForeignKey(Director, related_name='name boss')
```

**class school**, inherits the model of the director in the **director_name**

**class Director**, must also inherit the Boss class, for the director_name field

`school = models.CharField()`

But it doesn't work for obvious reasons

Django guru, tell me how to implement this task, please

I Googled everything I could but didn't find a solution.

Comment: The `Director` model shouldn't have a field `school`. You get the name of the school via the `director_name` connection (that should simply be called `director`)  that you define in the `School` model. And where does this mentioned `boss` class come from? The related name "name boss" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to have "school name" or similar on a `Director` then I'd suggest using a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). This will ensure that 1 director can only be linked to 1 school and visa versa.

Also it would be good [django] practice to rename the director field on the `School`.

```
from django.db import models


class Director(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Surname')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/img/", height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=10000, verbose_name='photo')
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='birthday')

    @property
    def name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    @property
    def school_name(self):
        return self.school.name


class School(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='name')
    capacity = models.IntegerField(max_length=20,verbose_name='capacity')
    registration_is = models.BooleanField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Registration')
    director = models.OneToOneField(Director, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def director_name(self):
        return self.director.name
```